# Sublime text shortcut to open keybindings and settings

Tags: sublimetext3, keyboard-shortcuts

I would like to be able to map a keyboard shortcut to be able to open the settings and open the keybindings.

I would like it to behave the exact same as going to Menu > Preference > Settings \ Keybindings.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 5):

If a command appears in a Menu or in the command palette, then it's possible to bind it to a key provided you can determine what the command is and what arguments it takes.

One way to determine that for a menu item is to use `View Package File` from the command palette and then open the appropriate menu resource. The main menu always comes from a `Main.sublime-menu` resource, so once you enter the command you can enter `Main.sublime-menu` in order to see all of the resources that match, then pick the one for the appropriate package.

For a command that appears in the command palette you can do the same by entering `sublime-commands` to see all of the files that are contributing commands to the command palette and then select the appropriate one to see what command it's executing.

For determining the command bound to a key (in case you want to go the other way and add it to a menu or the command palette) you would look for `sublime-keymap` files instead.

These options require you to either know the package that is contributing the command or be able to infer it based on what it does. The `Default` package is what contains the default Sublime behaviour; other files augment the files from that package.

Another method is to open the Sublime console with <kbd>Ctrl+`</kbd> or the menu item `View > Show Console` and then enter the command `sublime.log_commands(True)` to turn on command logging.

With that enabled you can take the action you want to know the command for and the console will tell you the command being executed and what arguments it's taking.

In your particular case, the output in the console would be:

```
command: edit_settings {"base_file": "${packages}/Default/Default ($platform).sublime-keymap", "default": "[\n\t$0\n]\n"}
command: new_window
```

The first of these is the appropriate command, and the second is that command executing a command of it's own to open a new window for the settings to be stored in.

Armed with that, you can make an appropriate key binding:

```json
{
    "keys": ["ctrl+alt+shift+k"],
    "command": "edit_settings", 
    "args": {
        "base_file": "${packages}/Default/Default ($platform).sublime-keymap", 
        "default": "[\n\t$0\n]\n"
    }
},
```

Note that recent (as of the time of this answer) builds of Sublime have a bug in which commands executed from the command palette don't always get logged, in which case if that's how you want to determine the correct command you would have to look in the resource directly.

Answer (score 0):

To add a more simple approach to [OdatNurd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/814803/odatnurd)'s fantastic answer: I recently found myself wanting a shortcut to open my keybindings file and came across a slightly longer route using the Command Pallet that I was content with.

This doesn't answer the specific issue of creating a **keyboard shortcut** to open the user's `.sublime-keymap` file, but it does solve the *general* issue of getting to that file in a timely manner, without having to use the mouse.

The approach is:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> *(Open Command Pallet)*
- Type: *"keybind"*

This gives:

[image: Command Pallet with "Preferences: Key Bindings" option highlighted]

Hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> and the user's `.sublime-keymap` file will be opened as it would be if you navigated to `Menu` > `Preferences` > `Key Bindings`.